# how to count distinct strings inside string vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a vb.net utility and have run into a need to find all the distinct strings inside a string.

So basically I will have a string that will look like this.
    `1.875{0};10;0.25|1.875;9;0.25|{2}1.875;1.875;0.25|14.125;{1}1.875;0.25|{0}14.125;16.125{1};0.25|1.875;{0}16.125;0.25|1.875;9;0.25{2}|1.875;8;0.25`

So you can see I have these chars inside the string {0}, {1}, {2}

There are however multiples of each "placeholder" so to speak.

So i need help writing a function that will take string string above and return a count of 3 in this example, because there are 3 distinct placeholders in the source string.  It would kind of mimick the distinct command in sql.

I'm sure this uses some kind of regex but I can't wrap my head around it to retrieve only the distinct ones.  Not all the multiples.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expressions and a little bit of LINQ you can achieve the desired effect

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Linq

Private Function CountPlaceholders(source As String) As Integer
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(source, "{[0-9]+}")
    Return matches.Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value).Distinct().Count()
End Function
```

First, find all the placeholders using a fairly straightforward regular expression. The `+` after the `[0-9]` numeric search will find one or more occurrences of a number so will find placeholders 0 through n.

The next line is what counts the distinct occurrences. Each item in the `matches` `MatchCollection` has to be cast to `Match` in order for the LINQ-to-Objects extensions to operate. After that, you select the `Value` property of the `Match` object, filter the distinct values, and count them.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you very much.  Taught me something new.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the regex `{\d+}` to do the match, but you are correct that will not give you a distinct list.  But you can loop over the Match collection returned by [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), extract the `Value` and use the [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) Linq method to get a list of the distinct entries.